# How to avoid storing userid/password in the .odbc.ini file on Linux?

Tags: odbc, teradata, unixodbc, stata

I am connecting to a Teradata database through ODBC with Stata on an Ubuntu server (12.04 LTS). Everything works fine, except that I have my TD userid and password stored in the .odbc.ini file, which seems like a terrible idea. The alternative is to enter them in Stata, which seems even worse and is awkward. Is there a way to do this more securely? The login info that I use to ssh into the server is synced with the TD database. It seems that it should be possible to pass that information along.

Answer (score 3):

In ODBC terms you do not need to store usernames / passwords in any of your ODBC ini files. Both the ODBC [SQLConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SQLDriverConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) support the passing in of username / password at the time they are called.

SQLDriverConnect would need something in your InConnectionString like "DSN=YourDataSourceName;UID=username;PWD=password".

You could go one step further and pass in the whole DSN as a command line argument thus meaning that you would not need an ODBC data source in an ini file. I'm sure one of the forum readers can post a sample for you from Teradata.

As for passing in the user name and password from your SSH loging. Your application would need to capture that and pass it to ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to establish a finer grain of security around your odbc.ini file or other files on your Ubuntu server that may contain user credentials I would strongly suggest the use of [Access Control Lists](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) (ACLs). Beyond the typical Owner::Group::World permissions you can specify permissions down to the specific user on whether they are allowed or denied an explicit permission for a given file.

Other options regarding security on Teradata include the use of LDAP authentication if your environment supports it. Configuring LDAP on Teradata is beyond the scope of SO and in many cases a billable, professional services engagement with Teradata's Information Security CoE.